# Examples of XMLSchemas with variable content models

Tags: xsd

I have been involved in developing XMLSchema models for a community domain (science) and find the variable content models very complicated and probably too complex for my community. I'd be very interested in successful public deployment of XML Schemas with variable content models (E.g. "salami slice", "venetian blind", "russian doll", "hermaphrodite", "garden of eden"). Roger Costello has done a first class job in systematising this (http://www.xfront.com/BestPracticesHomepage.html) - and I'm personally flattered that the `xml-dev` mailing list has created this document (in the same way as SAX was created).

There's some SO discussion at:
[What are best practices for designing XML schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231553/what-are-best-practices-for-designing-xml-schemas)

My current question is which of these approaches (or none) **is actually used**, so I'd be very interested in real examples of communities which have used this (or communities which have found any or all of the approaches too complex).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is not a very important area for most XML developers so I will assume that complex XML schema models are rare.